# Recorrer Objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo este json:

```
var json =    {
     "0":{
       "check":true,
       "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
         },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }}
     "1":{
      "check":true,
      "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
      },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }
     }
    }
```

Quisiera que si me llega 0 o 1, cambiar el valor de `ObJECT_ID` y `EVENT_NAME` a `true`

He probado hacer este for :

```
    for (var i in json) {
        console.log(json[i].nameTable)
    }
```

Segun me pasen 0 o 1, tengo que recorrer lo que hay dentro de ellos(en mi ejemplo solo tengo 2 el ObJECT_ID y EVENT_NAME pero tengo muchos más) y cambair el valor de check que hay dentro de ellos por true

Comment: No te acabo de entender; un poco de código, con un `if( ) ... else ...` de lo que quieres hacer, o algo similar, estaría bien :-)

Comment: acabo de editar al pregunta por si se aclara mejor

Comment: Quieres entrar a los campos "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE" y dentro de él comprobar el valor del campo "name" (que es, también, "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE")?

Comment: pregunta modificado para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Ahh, ¿te refieres a todos los hijos que tengan campo "check"?

Comment: si y ademas que la respuesta que me has dado sea más dinámico ya que tengo mas de 2 objetos

Comment: Vale, es que el texto "Quisiera que si me llega 0 o 1, cambiar el valor de ObJECT_ID y EVENT_NAME a true" confunde más que ayuda. Mira mi respuesta ahora, a ver si es lo que buscas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Comprueba el siguiente programa. En él se comprueba la existencia de la propiedad `check` de cada elemento para asignarle `true` en caso afirmativo.

```js
let json = {
      "0":{
       "check":true,
       "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
         },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }},
     "1":{
      "check":true,
      "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
      },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }
     }
    };
 
for (let i in json) {
  for (let j in json[i]) {
    if (json[i][j].hasOwnProperty('check')) {
      json[i][j].check = true;
    }
  }
}

console.log("Mostrando resultado final:");
console.log(json);
```

Según la edición que me proporcionas, es más eficiente hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let json = {
      "0":{
       "check":true,
       "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
         },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }},
     "1":{
      "check":true,
      "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
      },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }
     }
    };
 
/* Sólo debemos cambiar los elementos 0 y 1 si existen */
$scope.toggle = function(isCheck, index) {
 if (json.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
  /* No es necesario usar index.toString() */
   for (let j in json[index]) {
    if (json[index][j].hasOwnProperty('check')) {
      json[index][j].check = isCheck;
    }
   }
 }
}

console.log("Mostrando resultado final:");
console.log(json);
```

Si recibes, como dices en tu pregunta, 50 o más registros es un desperdicio de tiempo recorrer todos y cada uno de los elementos si sólo buscas dos en concreto, el índice `0` y el `1`.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero si hago esto 
if (json[i].hasOwnProperty('OBJECT_ID')) {
      json[i].OBJECT_ID.check = true;
    }
imaginate que tenga OBJECT_ID1, OBJECT_ID2 ...OBJECT_ID50, tndria que ser algo más dinámico

Comment: Editado, no entendí bien tu consulta y creo que ahora sí.

Comment: gracias me valio tu respuesta, como casi siempre jeje

Comment: He rechazado tu edición, mira la edición que he hecho, es más eficiente porque sólo comprueba dos elementos.

Comment: he modificado tu respuesta porque lo que necesitaba era eso, simplemente no me hecho entender muy bien lo que queria

Comment: Vuelve a editar que ha sido rechazada (esta vez de manera automática) al haber coincidido con una edición mía (he agregado el texto `/* Sólo debemos cambiar los elementos 0 y 1 si existen */`).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57808/discussion-between-sirdaiz-and-oscargarcia).

Comment: He mejorado tu edición. De nuevo es innecesario recorrer los elementos del json hasta llegar al índice deseado, con comprobar su existencia basta (`json.hasOwnProperty(index)`).

Comment: @OscarGarcia para mejorar un poco tu respuesta cambiaria el var por let

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow, es una mala costumbre heredada... voy a cambiarlo.

Answer (score 3):

A ver si te he entendido bien.

¿Quieres poner a *true* las propiedades *check* del elemento que te indiquen?

Si es así aquí tienes un ejemplo en el que una función recibe el *id* del elemento a modificar y el objeto json y modifica sus propiedades *check*.

```js
var json =    {
     "0":{
       "check":true,
       "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
         },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }},
     "1":{
      "check":true,
      "OBJECT_ID":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"OBJECT_ID",
      },
      "nameTable":"TEST1",
      "EVENT_NAME_MANAGE":{
         "check":false,
         "name":"EVENT_NAME_MANAGE",
      }
     }
    }
    
function check(id, jsonObject){
  if (jsonObject[id] && jsonObject[id].OBJECT_ID){
    jsonObject[id].OBJECT_ID.check = true;
  }
  if (jsonObject[id] && jsonObject[id].EVENT_NAME_MANAGE){
    jsonObject[id].EVENT_NAME_MANAGE.check = true;
  }  
}

check('1', json);

console.log(json);
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, con la respuesta de oscar ya lo solucione